# setInterval calling a function every n seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a road block with calling a function every 1 second.  The code runs once when the page is loaded and if I manually refresh the page it runs again.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
//query the function S1M1StatusInt every second

setInterval(function () {S1M1StatusInt()}, 1000);
```

The Test_tag below is an int ranging 0-4 :="Skid 1".Test_tag: is the syntax to address a PLC tag.

```
// Change the Skid 1 Meter 1 block from grey to red or green based on "Skid 1".Test_tag

function S1M1StatusInt() {
    var dim1= :="Skid 1".Test_tag:;

    switch (dim1)
    {
    case 1:
        document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className ="";
        document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className = "RedBlock";
        break;
    case 2:
        document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className ="";
        document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className = "RedBlock";
        break;
    case 3: 
        document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className ="";
        document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className = "GreenBlock";
        break;
    }}
```

-----Edit for epascarello-----

```
function CheckS1M1StatusInt(){
    $.ajax({
        Type: "Get",
        url: "Meter_Status/S1M1_Status.htm",
        data: {*** what goes in here if I am retreving data***},
        success: successCheck,
        error: errorcheck
    });
}

function successCheck(data){
    switch (data)
                {
                case 1:
                    document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className ="";
                    document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className = "RedBlock";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className ="";
                    document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className = "RedBlock";
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className ="";
                    document.getElementById("S1M1Status").className = "GreenBlock";
                    break;
                };
    Console.log(data);
    window.setTimeout(checkServer,1000);
}

function errorCheck(){
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error in the console?

Comment: because you have syntax error `var dim1= :="Skid 1".Test_tag:;` that is not valid javascript

Comment: @epascarello: It says right there in the question what the problem is.

Comment: *FYI:* `setInterval(S1M1StatusInt, 1000);` is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the browser does not keep updating serverside code. The PLC tag [whatever that is] is rendered one time, it does not keep getting the new value from the server. That is why it never changes.

What you would need to do is make an Ajax call to the server and check the status.

```
function checkServer() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URLToPageToCheck/foo.php",
    data: { "itemX" : "whatYouWantToSendUp"},
    success: successCheck,
    error: errorCheck
  });
}

function successCheck(data){
   //Logic Check Here
   console.log(data);
   //Call checkServer again with a delay
   window.setTimeout(checkServer,1000);   
}
function errorCheck(){
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ The success callback would contain the logic in S1M1StatusInt. The serverside would return back the value you would want to check. When the call is done, you call call the server again.

Comment: The ajax file can be pretty much anything. You could have your program output and update a file with a simple JSON array like `{'plc':1}` where 1 can be your 0-4 integer. When using the `.get()` function you can easily return that result and parse the JSON into a array to use on your program like `result.plc`

Comment: @epascarello I am not trying put anything to the url file, i am trying to do a get. I am new to all of this coding and thank you very much for the help.

Please see the edit to my original post for my best guess at implementing what you have provided.

Comment: You need to make a call to something on the server that gives you the status. The variable in the clientside is not going to update. I do not know the framework so I can only give the generic answer.

Comment: The PLC automatically updates the  "S1M1_Status.htm" file.  That htm file has a PLC specific line of code to address the PLC value. For instance if I put a counter program on the PLC using variable XYZ. If I load the S1M1_Status.htm on the PLC's internal webserver and manually refresh the page it will update and output the value of XYZ with each refresh.

How would I retrieve the value from S1M1_Status.htm? Is my edit even close?

Comment: Than make a page that just has that value and request it with the Ajax code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dim1= :="Skid 1".Test_tag:;
```

This is complete nonsense. The parse failure causes your function execution to fail in a manner so spectacular that the entire timer is killed.

Comment: what LRiO said, is that you have written is not valid javascript. Strings do not have a property called Test_tag and both of the colons are totaly malplaced

Comment: down votes would be because OP already explains that this mysterious format is part of some other system - no different to say... PHP? `<?=$foo->$bar?>` (hadn't heard of PLC myself but a quick google search turns up [this](http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8567/siemens-s7-1200-web-server-tutorial--from-getting-started-to-html5-user-defined-pages))

Comment: @Emissary: The question is tagged JavaScript. This answer pertains to JavaScript. The code in the question is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

To begin with this

```
setInterval(function () {S1M1StatusInt()}, 1000);
```

Should simply be

```
setInterval(S1M1StatusInt, 1000);
```

And here, you have an extremely malformed statement which causes an error. PLC is a separate language from JavaScript, HTML, and other forms of web markup and will not work.

```
 var dim1= :="Skid 1".Test_tag:;
```

Also, you can set the class name without clearing it with jQuery

```
 Object.attr('class', 'className');
```

Or using the toggleClass or addClass / removeClass functions. Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)